# Tracking mouse movement and magnitude

Tags: c#, xna

I'm making a simple game where the player controls a tank. The rotation of the turret will be controlled by mouse movements. The code currently looks like this:

```
if (Game.MouseState.Y < yMovementBorder)
   PossessedTurretPitchValue += dist;

if (Game.MouseState.Y > yMovementBorder)
   PossessedTurretPitchValue -= dist;

if (Game.MouseState.X < xMovementBorder)
   PossessedTurretYaw += rotationDist / 6;

if (Game.MouseState.X > xMovementBorder)
   PossessedTurretYaw -= rotationDist / 6;
```

xMovementBorder and yMovementBorder are values representing the midpoint of the game screen. The problem is that any  movement of the mouse will cause the turret to turn until its maximum pitch/yaw angle. How can I make it such that it will be able to read the mouse movement as well as its magnitude(ie: slight movement of the mouse will only cause a slight pitch/yaw movement of the turret)?

Comment: what is `yMovementBorder`?

Comment: yMovementBorder is the value representing the midpoint of the screen for the purposes of y-axis movement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your update method, you should store references to your previous mouse state and current mouse state. Then use these two variables to figure out how much the mouse moved since the last update. It will take some tweaking to get it just right, but try something like this:

```
//define your private variables
private MouseState prevMouseState = null;
private MouseState currMouseState = Game.MouseState;

public void Update(GameTime gt)
{
    prevMouseState = currMouseState;
    currMouseState = Game.MouseState;

    //calculate how much the mouse has moved since the last update
    var dX = currMouseState.X - prevMouseState.X;
    var dY = currMouseState.Y - prevMouseState.Y;

    //do your rotating depending on the values of dX and dY
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Would this only work with    Update(Gametime gt)   though? My tank has an AI-controlled mode and a player-controlled mode. The code in the OP was for the player-controlled mode, which is a function    private void InPossessedTankMode(float dist, float rotationDist, GameTime gameTime)    , called from a switch

Comment: No you should be able to use this same exact code in your `InPossessedTankMode` function. You might just need to modify what parameters you pass into it. If you need more help, post both functions in your question and I will elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is set limits based on how far from center the mouse is.

Like:

```
if (Game.MouseState.Y < yMovementBorder)
    if (PossessedTurretPitchValue < yMovementBorder*someFactor)
        PossessedTurretPitchValue += dist;
```

And similarly for the other three cases.

Without setting a limit, *any* deviation from the center will cause the turret to move.  It will be moving all the time, and eventually rail somewhere.  This is what your code does now, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I already have limits for the turret implemented elsewhere in the code though.